# How did Google Music for iOS access data from another iOS App?

Tags: ios

Today I downloaded the new Google Music app for iOS and it immediately had me signed in already. I assume they accomplished this using one of the other Google Apps on my phone. To keep this appropriate for StackOverflow, here's the question, specific and objective:

How (technically) can an app (like Google Music) authenticate a user using data from another app (like Google Search or Google Chrome)? I was under the impression that apps in iOS were entirely sand boxed.

I'm very curious in finding a technical explanation for this, so if someone could recommend a way to rephrase or retag the question, please feel free to edit or migrate.

Comment: I'm not sure what technology Google Music app used,but do some search for SSO(Single sign-on), maybe that is what you want!

Answer (score 3):

iOS Keychain can be shared with your other apps via access groups, see [this](http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/) for example.